# How to rearrange FID numeration programmatically?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, vba

I've got a feature class

[image]

Now, I delete the selected features programmatically using `pFeature.Delete` :

[image]

Is there any command or function in VBA which rearranges the FID field and makes the numeration to begin from 0 like in the picture below?

[image]

Or may be it is possible to delete the features programmatically  without corrupting FID numeration, like the manual deleting do it.

Starting and stopping editing doesn't solve the problem (the code deletes selected features of the first layer):

```
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
Dim pSelectionSet As ISelectionSet
Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
Dim pFeature As IFeature
Dim pDataSet As IDataset
Dim pFC As IFeatureClass
Dim pUID As New UID
Dim pEditor As IEditor

Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
Set pFeatureLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
Set pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer
Set pFC = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass
Set pSelectionSet = pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet
Set pDataSet = pFC

pSelectionSet.Search Nothing, False, pFeatureCursor
Set pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature

pUID = "esriEditor.Editor"
Set pEditor = Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pUID)
pEditor.StartEditing pDataSet.Workspace
pFeature.Delete
pEditor.StopEditing True
```

If you execute the Sub below then the FID numbers will be reaaranged! In the end, solution is to start and stop editing in another Sub (not in the same).

```
Private Sub rearrangeFID()

Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pDataSet As IDataset
Dim pFC As IFeatureClass
Dim pUID As New UID
Dim pEditor As IEditor

Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
Set pFeatureLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
Set pFC = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass
Set pDataSet = pFC

pUID = "esriEditor.Editor"
Set pEditor = Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pUID)
pEditor.StartEditing pDataSet.Workspace
pEditor.StopEditing True

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot control the "FID" column associated with a shapefile. It is ***not*** a real field, just a record number (zero-based). When you stop editing the component files will be rewtitten and the values will be resequenced to what you have requested.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've edited a question (adding a code), what do I do wrong? I start an editing and stop it, but FID numbers are not resequenced .

Comment: Instead of writing to a ShapeFile if you write to a personal GeoDatabase and then compact it that should give your re-order ID column. Note the ObjectID starts at 1 not 0.

Comment: Try StartEditing before selecting `pFeature`

Comment: I've never deal with GeoDatabase, but I've found a solution. May be It's not very correct, but it works right in my case (codeis in the end of question)

Comment: In a GDB (File, Personal and SDE) the OID (Object ID) is *static* and remains with the feature for its' entire life - from create to delete... this value is managed by the database and **should not be modified**; shapefiles have a FID which is 0 based and ascending, compacted on save, and **is pointless to modify** as they will be reordered on the next save. The difference between the OID and FID is profound and needs to be remembered when trying to join using these fields or call a feature by its' ID. @Vince is correct, **don't even try to modify ids** or risk breaking the feature class.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use the `Copy Features` tool, which assigns a new, consecutive number scheme to the new featureclass.